# After a migration Model doesn't show up in my Schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration

I've tried to solve this issue a few times now, but with no luck.

I recently switched my app over to Postgress from Sqlite3, but a now having issues generating models in Rails. The weird thing is that when I run a Rake db:migrate my terminal window states that the tables were created successfully. Although when I look into my Schema file the nearly created model doesn't show up. The model's attributes aren't accessible through rails console, which seems to let me know that the model doesn't yet exist in the database.

Am I wrong in my assumptions, or do you guys think there is something else going on here? I've googled this issue, but can't seem to find any relevant posts regarding this issue, so any help or suggestions is welcome.

Comment: When you connect manually with the postgres client (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/app-psql.html) and use `\d` to list tables, do you see the new tables?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the tables are created outside your search path.

Try `\dn` to list namespaces and then

```
\d myschema.*
```

To list all structures of tables within my schema.  You can also

```
SET search_path = 'myschema';
\d
RESET search_path;
```